# How to add pagination in table using d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

i have following code,i have to add pagination on this table

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>table</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<style> 
 .rect {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
</style> 
</head>
<body>

<div id="table"></div>
<script>
var data = [{
  "name": "a",
  "section": 1,
  "stars": "d1"
}, {
  "name": "b",
  "section": 2,
  "stars": "d2"
}, {
  "name": "c",
  "section": 1,
  "stars": "d3"
}];

var columns = ['name', 'section', 'stars']
  // create table
var table = d3.select("#table").append("table");

var thead = table.append("thead").append("tr");

thead.selectAll("th")
  .data(columns)
  .enter()
  .append("th")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

var tbody = table.append("tbody");

data.forEach(function(d, i) {
  trow = tbody.append("tr")
  trow.selectAll("td")
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .append(function(d) {
      if (d == "stars") {
        return document.createElement('button');
      } else
        return document.createElement('div');
    })
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      if (d == "section") {
        return "rect"
      }
    })
    .text(function(e) {
      return d[e]
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

how to add pagination in d3?
i have to set pagination for each two rows,please suggest the solution.
just i have added 3 rows of data but my actual data contains 50 to 100 rows

Answer (score 3):

At the simplest level you just control the visibility/display of the table rows. This example is as basic as you get , it uses two buttons to show different groups of ten in a table - no page numbering, no limiting, no styling :-) - but it does the pagination

http://jsfiddle.net/f50mggof/6/

```
<div id="buttons">
<button id="up">
UP
</button>
<button id="down">
DOWN
</button>
</div>
<table></table>


var dataset = [];
for (var n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
    dataset.push ([n, Math.random()*50, Math.random()*30]);
}

var rows = d3.select("table").selectAll("tr").data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("tr")
  ;

  var cells = rows.selectAll("td").data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
  ;

  d3.select("#buttons").datum({portion : 0});
  // the chain select here pushes the datum onto the up and down buttons also
  d3.select("#buttons").select("#up").on ("click", function(d) {
    d.portion -= 10;
    redraw (d.portion);
  });
   d3.select("#buttons").select("#down").on ("click", function(d) {
    d.portion += 10;
    redraw (d.portion);
  })

  function redraw (start) {
    d3.select("table").selectAll("tr")
        .style("display", function(d,i) {
        return i >= start && i < start + 10 ? null : "none";
      })
  }
  redraw(0);
```

Comment: i have to set pager based on table rows

Comment: pager like 1,2,3,4

Comment: pager on also set based on rows