# How to paginate multiple HTML tbodies with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have this table drawn from d3 where it has grouped entries that are in separate tbodies so the entries stay grouped when sorted.  I am using the tablesorter plugin to help sort the tbodies which as been nothing but awesome, however at this point, you cannot use their pagination widget with the sortable tbodies one.

I have d3 handling all the table drawing, so it would be great if there was a plugin out there that can handle this.  I had to use d3 this time since I needed a sortable nested table that wouldn't case the groups to break apart when sorting, otherwise the datatables plugin would have been good.  It's sort of like a billing statement where you can view several accounts that have a summary and then the details. D3 allowed the nested groupings to happen and the tablesorter plugin was great to allow sorting of both the details and the totals of the data. Is there a way D3 or any other tool can do pagination for all the tbodies?

To solve this problem, I tried to use traditional paginators, but those only work on regular tables.  This is a D3 table that has nested tables and it's important it can sort on the details and summaries.  Here's a fiddle of what I am dealing with: 
 https://jsfiddle.net/mcsmitheslc/mns6183o/

This is a paginator I had somewhat working, but it seems like overkill do do it all by hand like this:

```
    // Paginate the table, there's a plugin but it's not able to handle the nesting yet
    $('.paginated').each(function () {
        var $table = $(this);
        var itemsPerPage = 25;
        var currentPage = 0;
        var pages = Math.ceil($table.find("tr.detail-row:not(:has(th))").length / itemsPerPage);
        var allRows = merged.length;
        var shownRows = $('#table .detail-row:visible').length;

        $table.bind('repaginate', function () {
            if (pages > 1) {
                var pager;
                if ($table.next().hasClass("pager")) {
                    pager = $table.next().empty();
                } else
                    pager = $('<div class="pager" id="" style="padding-top: 20px; direction:ltr; " align="center"></div>');

                $('<button class="button hollow" id="first-button"></button>').text(' « First ').bind('click', function () {
                    currentPage = 0;
                    $table.trigger('repaginate');

                }).appendTo(pager);

                $('<button class="button hollow" id="previous-button"> « Prev </button>').bind('click', function () {
                    if (currentPage > 0)
                        currentPage--;
                    $table.trigger('repaginate');
                }).appendTo(pager);

                var startPager = currentPage > 2 ? currentPage - 2 : 0;
                var endPager = startPager > 0 ? currentPage + 3 : 5;
                if (endPager > pages) {
                    endPager = pages;
                    startPager = pages - 5;
                    if (startPager < 0)
                        startPager = 0;
                }

                for (var page = startPager; page < endPager; page++) {
                    $('<button id="pager-button" class="button tiny"><span id="pg' + page + '" class="' + (page == currentPage ? 'pg-selected' : 'pg-normal') + '"></span></button>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
                        newPage: page
                    }, function (event) {
                        currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
                        $table.trigger('repaginate');
                    }).appendTo(pager);
                }

                $('<button class="button hollow" id="next-button"> Next » </button>').bind('click', function () {
                    if (currentPage < pages - 1)
                        currentPage++;
                    $table.trigger('repaginate');
                    console.log('Viewing ' +currentPage);
                }).appendTo(pager);
                $('<button class="button hollow" id="last-button"> Last » </button>').bind('click', function () {
                    currentPage = pages - 1;
                    $table.trigger('repaginate');
                    var rowCount = $('#table tbody tr').length;
                    var numOfVisibleRows = $('tbody tr:visible').length;
                    var diff = currentPage * 25;
                    var remainingRows = allRows - diff;
                    console.log('Viewing ' +currentPage);
                    console.log(diff + 'sliced' +remainingRows + ' on the last page');
                }).appendTo(pager);

                if (!$table.next().hasClass("pager"))
                    pager.insertAfter($table);
            }
            $table.find(
                'tbody tr:not(:has(th))').hide().slice(currentPage * itemsPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * itemsPerPage).show();

        });

        $table.trigger('repaginate');

    });
```

Comment: Not sure about your requirement. check this https://datatables.net/. This can be used to sort, paginate and search. might help you

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Hey @Christina, I do remember seeing your question about this nested/grouped table but couldn't find the time to answer it. Anyway, if you could include the said table as a snippet in this question, it'd be easier to provide a solution. As far as pagination goes, I don't think there is any specific d3 plugin for that but [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615512/how-to-add-pagination-in-table-using-d3) might definitely be useful and to get started with.

Comment: @Kuru, I have used datatables in the past, but it won't work this time since it fails when I am keeping groups together upon sorting the various columns in the table

Comment: Thanks @Shashank.  The link you posted is a start.  I have a count of my tbodies and I have d3 now doing something similar.  It's successfully clicking through it in groups of ten.  Still a couple more things to take care of on it like how to handle things when "up" is past 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you came back with what you've tried until now based off the comment I posted. I couldn't work on it yesterday as I got too busy with work. Anyway, got it working now.

I made a few changes to it and also added certain additional features (First, Prev, Next, Last) and seems to be working okay now.

HTML added:

```
<div id="toggle-buttons">
<button class="button" data-id="first">
          First Page
        </button>
<button class="button disabled" data-id="previous">
          Prev Page
        </button>
<button class="button" data-id="next">
          Next Page
        </button>
<button class="button" data-id="last">
          Last Page
        </button>            
<button class="button" id="all-button">
          Show All
</button>
</div>
```

Javascript to paginate the table based on the button click:

```
const totalBodies = $('tbody').length;
var counter = 0; // set counter initially to 0

d3.selectAll('#toggle-buttons button').on('click', function () {

if(d3.select(this).classed('disabled'))
    return ;

switch(d3.select(this).attr('data-id')) {
    case 'first':
        counter = 0;
    d3.select(this.parentNode).select('[data-id="previous"]').classed('disabled', true);
    d3.select(this.parentNode).select('[data-id="next"]').classed('disabled', false);
            break;
  case 'last':
        counter = totalBodies-1;
    d3.select(this.parentNode).select('[data-id="next"]').classed('disabled', true);        
    d3.select(this.parentNode).select('[data-id="previous"]').classed('disabled', false);        
    break;
  case 'next':
            counter++;
    if(counter === totalBodies-1) {
        d3.select(this).classed('disabled', true);
    }
        d3.select(this.parentNode).select('[data-id="previous"]').classed('disabled', false);         
    break;
  case 'previous':
            counter--;
    if(!counter) {
        d3.select(this).classed('disabled', true);
    }
        d3.select(this.parentNode).select('[data-id="next"]').classed('disabled', false);         
            break;
}
redraw(counter);
});
```

Explanation (pretty much understandable I suppose):

1. Switch case to determine the button click based on which the counter will change. **Important** Toggling the `disabled` class on the buttons.
2. `redraw(counter)` on every button click (unless it has a disabled class)

Here's a fork of your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/noxg31eq/

I'm selecting the first page by default. You can change that according to the requirement and add the `disabled` class in the initial phase accordingly. Also, I see a `table` nested within a `table` which doesn't seem right - maybe `tablesorter` adds a `table` tag as well. You can take a look at that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for looking at this.  I believe that is from tablesorter as well.  It looks like the last step I have is to show all of them :)

Comment: Yes, you'll have to do the last step. (If I would've done that for you, my answer would've been downvoted for answering much more than the requirement :p ). Anyway, glad I could help :)

Comment: No worries, I got it.  Thank you for clearing that for me.  It was getting complicated to make by hand otherwise.

Comment: Sure. No sweat! But I still think we should be able to make the **tablesorter built-in pagination** work in this case. Anyway, custom pagination can now be turned into a plugin as well.

Comment: Haha, indeed. That would be quite useful since these kinds of tables provide overall a nice user experience for someone wanting the tables like an Exvel pivot table right in the browser

Comment: Exactly. Guess what, I wrote a pretty decent pivot table/viz plugin last week at work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got some of it myself based off what Shashank posted:

```
        let tbodiesPerPage = 10;
    const totalBodies = $('tbody').length;

    d3.select("#buttons").datum({
        portion: 0
    });

    // the chain select here pushes the datum onto the up and down buttons also
    d3.select("#buttons").select("#previous-button").on("click", function (d) {
        console.log('next was ', d.portion);
        if (d.portion - tbodiesPerPage >= 0) {
            d.portion -= tbodiesPerPage;
            redraw(d.portion);
        }
    });

    d3.select("#buttons").select("#next-button").on("click", function (d) {
        // let the bodies hit the floor
        console.log('previous was', d.portion);
        if (d.portion < (totalBodies - tbodiesPerPage)) {
            d.portion += tbodiesPerPage;
            redraw(d.portion);
        }
    });

    function redraw(start) {
        d3
            .select("table")
            .selectAll("tr")
            .style("display", function (d, i) {
                return i >= start && i < start + tbodiesPerPage ? null : "none";
            });
    }

    redraw(0);
```